# header that becomes fixed on scroll

Tags: wordpress, header

Im Looking for some ideas on how to achieve a delayed fixed header? something similar to that on the site itsnicethat.com
Where the header on becomes fixed after you scroll further down on a page. I’m looking to implement it for a client using Wordpress?

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated,

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the most straightforward way is to monitor scrollTop and change the style or toggle a class for the header that sets it as fixed/normal